# Downloading zip files with http.get on node.js

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

I'm having problem downloading a file from URL using http.get. Response statusCode returns as 302, but when I try the same url with Firefox using HttpFox extension I can see a status code 200 and an additional header, "content-disposition: inline; filename=test.zip". Browsers handle these URL's correctly, and open a save as dialog. How should I handle this URL in Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

"Response statusCode returns as 302" means redirect to another URL.

Browsers handles such response automatically. You have to do that by hands. The new URL is provided in the `Location` header. Just do another http.get from this URL.

Comment: Actually I am redirecting on 302, but the response.header.location returns the same url.